# Django admin - add more controls to the field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

The goal is to add custom input and a button to Django admin panel. It is described on the image (marked with green):

[image]

The problem is that Django admin uses database to display its stuff. Inline components doesn't fit here, because the rest of the rows don't have these controls.

Comment: I'm thinking of something a lot easier, perhaps a custom form instead of a button? Let me write the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import forms
import datetime

class AddDaysForm(forms.ModelForm):
    add_extra_days_to_subscription_expiry = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance:
            self.base_fields['add_extra_days_to_subscription_expiry'] = 0
        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class SubscriptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    form = AddDaysForm
    list_display = ('id', 'domain', 'domain_created',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if form.cleaned_data['add_extra_days_to_subscription_expiry'] != 0:
            obj.subscription_expire = obj.subscription_expire + datetime.timedelta(days=form.cleaned_data['add_extra_days_to_subscription_expiry'])
            obj.save()
```

With this solution, you simply enter a number and then hit save via the admin, and it will add it for you. When the form reloads, it will reset back to 0 so that you can enter a new value. Note, that it also accounts for when the form is saved from the default '0' value.